# Flask-Login and Flask-SocketIO current_user.is_authenticated issue

Tags: flask, flask-login, flask-socketio

I am using Flask-Login to log in users and wanted to be able to log out a user (I want to track session times) if they closed their browser before manually logging out of the Flask app.

This can be done with Flask-SocketIO:

```
@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect_user():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        logged_out = logout_user()
        logger.debug('logged_out OK: {0}, current_user.is_authenticated: {1}'.format(logged_out, current_user.is_authenticated))
```

NB you need to run the client JS as per the docs for SocketIO

About a minute after closing the browser the disconnect_user method runs and prints "logged_out OK: True, current_user.is_authenticated: False". All good, however when I open the browser again and call current_user.is_authenticated as per below it returns True!

home.html:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    {% if not current_user.is_authenticated %}
        <li ><a href="{{ url_for('view.index') }}">Index</a></li>
    {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('app.user_link') }}">User link</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
```

It seems odd to me that current_user.is_authenticated is clearly False, then returns True for same server session but different browser sessions. Any idea what is going on and how to get around this?

As requested login and user model code:

```
@auth_view.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if current_user is not None and current_user.is_authenticated:
        flash("Already logged in.", 'info')
        return redirect(url_for('main_view.index'))
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #find user in db then
        login_user(user)

def User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    #password code here

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
```

Comment: it's now a boolean property, nothing wrong with my calling it. See https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Can you please post your code for login and models?

Comment: @MohammadAmin I added code to question

Comment: You need  to change is_authenticated and other methods to properties with the @property decorator. Or for the sake of the argument, you can just: from flask.ext.login import UserMixin and pass it to your user model. Remove your is_authenticated method and compare the results.

Comment: @MohammadAmin I think you might be on the right track. Though I'm getting a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable error when I call login_user(user) where user has the get_id() method as property. Will take be a bit of time to work out why. With the 3 is_ methds as properties I'm still getting the same issue as in my original question

Comment: @login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)